# stop apache cassandra from starting automatically

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

The [documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html) of installing Apache Cassandra states that:

> However, normally the service will start automatically.

Once you have it installed, and it does when I turn on the computer. How can I stop it from starting automatically?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `sudo update-rc.d cassandra disable` in a terminal window